# Mock objects - Setup method - Test Driven Development

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, tdd, moq

I am learning Test Driven Development and trying to use Moq library for mocking. What is the purpose of Setup method of Mock class?

Answer (score 78):

The default behaviour of a Moq `Mock` object is to stub all methods and properties. This means that a call to that method/property with any parameters will not fail and will return a default value for the particular return type.

You call `Setup` method for any or all of the following reasons:

- You want to restrict the input values to the method.

```
public interface ICalculator {
  int Sum(int val1, val2);
}

var mock = new Mock<ICalculator>();
mock.Setup(m=>m.Sum(
  It.IsAny<int>(), //Any value
  3                //value of 3
));
```

The above setup will match a call to method `Sum` with any value for `val1` and `val2` value of 3.

- You want to return a specific value. Continuing with `ICalculator` example, the following setup will return a value of 10 regardless of the input parameters:

```
var mock = new Mock<ICalculator>();
mock.Setup(m=>m.Sum(
  It.IsAny<int>(), //Any value
  It.IsAny<int>()  //Any value
)).Returns(10);
```

- You want to use `Mock<T>.VerifyAll()` after you setups to verify that all previous setups have been called (once).

```
var mock = new Mock<ICalculator>();
mock.Setup(m=>m.Sum(
  7, //value of 7
  3                //value of 3
));

mock.Setup(m=>m.Sum(
  5, //value of 5
  3                //value of 3
));

mock.VerifyAll();
```

The above code verifies that `Sum` is called twice. Once with `(7,3)` and once with `(5,3)`.

Comment: I did not realize that one could simply call Setup() more than once to set up a multiple different parameters, and this is the only place I have seen it.

Comment: how can I do that Sum method will return custom exception message when it is involved? is it .Throws(new Exception("Test Message"))?

Answer (score 24):

Setup method is used to set expectations on the mock object
For example:

```
mock.Setup(foo => foo.DoSomething("ping")).Returns(true);
```

Here you are setting the `DoSomething` method on mock object. You are saying, when the parameter is "ping", the method returns true.

Now this object can further act as a mock or a stub depending on your usage. If you want to use it in state based testing, it can act as a stub. If you want to use it in behavior based testing, it can act as a mock. In behavior testing, you will call the verify method on the mock object to assert that the method was called with "ping" parameter

Further refer these links:

http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html

https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart