# How to check that an error is logged in a unit test for ASP.NET Core 3.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, moq, asp.net-core-3.0, xunit.net

I want to create a unit test to ensure that a method is logging an error using xUnit and Moq. This code worked in ASP.NET Core 2.1:

```
//Arrange
var logger = new Mock<ILogger<MyMiddleware>>();
var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();

var middleware = new MyMiddleware(request => Task.FromResult(httpContext), logger.Object);

//Act
await middleware.InvokeAsync(httpContext);

//Assert
logger.Verify(x => x.Log(LogLevel.Error, It.IsAny<EventId>(), It.IsAny<FormattedLogValues>(), It.IsAny<Exception>(), It.IsAny<Func<object, Exception, string>>()), Times.Once);
```

To validate that `_logger.LogError("Error message");` was called in `middleware.InvokeAsync`.

However, in ASP.NET Core 3.0, I am unable to verify that the logger is being called. `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Internal` can no longer be referenced, so `FormattedLogValues` is unavailable.

I tried changing the `Assert()` to use `object` instead of `FormattedLogValues`, and also `IReadOnlyList<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` since that is what `FormattedLogValues` is based on ([FormattedLogValues.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/Internal/FormattedLogValues.cs)).

This is the error message I am getting in the Visual Studio test runner:

```
Message: 
    Moq.MockException : 
    Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: x => x.Log<object>(LogLevel.Error, It.IsAny<EventId>(), It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<Exception>(), It.IsAny<Func<object, Exception, string>>())

  Performed invocations:

    ILogger.Log<FormattedLogValues>(LogLevel.Error, 0, Error message, null, Func<FormattedLogValues, Exception, string>)

  Stack Trace: 
    Mock.Verify(Mock mock, LambdaExpression expression, Times times, String failMessage)
    Mock`1.Verify(Expression`1 expression, Times times)
    Mock`1.Verify(Expression`1 expression, Func`1 times)
    MyMiddlewareTests.InvokeAsync_ErrorIsLogged() line 35
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

How can I validate the error is being logged in ASP.NET Core 3.0?

Comment: Add [a setup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3179782/884561) for the Log method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [an issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/1319) on the aspnet github page about this. It seems the problem is with `Moq` and they have made changes to fix it.

You will need to upgrade to `Moq 4.13` to get the fix.

They have introduced an `It.IsAnyType` to resolve the problem with internal objects so you should be able to change the `object` reference to `It.IsAnyType` and write your test like this:

```
logger.Verify(x => x.Log(LogLevel.Error, It.IsAny<EventId>(), It.IsAny<It.IsAnyType>(), It.IsAny<Exception>(), (Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>)It.IsAny<object>()), Times.Once);
```

Note: The last parameter needs to be type cast as `Moq` doesn't currently support nested type matchers.

More details from `Moq` can be found [here](https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/918#issuecomment-527647423)

Comment: How can you verify the message that was passed to the Log method?

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit late, but I just want to add that if you are asserting for specific messages being logged, you can create a custom matcher that inspects the message:

```
 logger.Verify(x => x.Log(LogLevel.Error,
      It.IsAny<EventId>(),
      It.Is<It.IsAnyType>((x, _) => LogMessageMatcher(x, "Expected error message")),
     It.IsAny<Exception>(),
     It.IsAny<Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>>()), Times.Once);
```

The MatcherMethod would be a static method like so:

```
     public static bool LogMessageMatcher(object formattedLogValueObject, string message)
    {
        var logValues = formattedLogValueObject as IReadOnlyList<KeyValuePair<string, object>>;
        return logValues.FirstOrDefault(logValue => logValue.Key == "{OriginalFormat}")
                         .Value.ToString() == message;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use SGA (Setup, Grab, Assert) approach.

```
//In the setup part
var mockLog = new Mock<ILogger>(MockBehavior.Strict);
string error = null;
mockLog.Setup(l => l
    .Error(It.IsAny<Exception>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Callback((Exception b, string c) =>
    {
        error = c + " " + b.GetBaseException().Message;
        // This would keep only the last error, but it's OK, since there should be zero
        // Sometimes I use a collection and append the error info.
    });


//In the assert part
Assert.IsNull(error, $"Error detected: {error}");
```